# Sequence of an exponential random variable

Tags: probability, convergence-divergence, random-variables, exponential-distribution

Given that $X_n$ is an exponential random variable with parameter $λ=n$.

How does $P(X_n≥ε)=e^{-nε}$ ?

According to this [probability course](https://www.probabilitycourse.com/chapter7/7_2_5_convergence_in_probability.php), the equality holds since $X_n∼Exponential(n)$.

Honestly, that's no real explanation; it's only common sense and already provided by the context.

Is there a formula for this? I can't seem to find anything online.

What I do know is that based on the WLLN:

$$P(X_n≥ε)=P\big(\big|\frac{X_1+...+X_n}{n}\big|≥ε\big)$$

So, by substituting in $X_n∼Exponential(n)$, this is what I get

$$P(X_n≥ε)=P\big(\big|\frac{e^1+...+e^n}{n}\big|≥ε\big)$$

Am I on the right track? How does this simplify to $e^{-nε}$?

I would highly appreciate any input on this. Thanks!

Comment: the density of the  is $\lambda \times exp(-\lambda x) $ so if you integrate that from $\epsilon$ to $\infty$ you will get the expression in your question.

Comment: $P(X_n \ge \epsilon) = 1 - P( X_n \le \epsilon)$

Comment: No need to worry about convergence of the sequence $X_n$, this is just the cdf for any particular $X_n$

Comment: Thanks @markleeds integration is exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: I found the same approach on wikipedia @layabout , where the CDF of an exp r.v. is $1-e^{-x}$ which is found by integrating the PDF as pointed out by markleeds